# Mockjax twice in same test file?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, mockjax

Using Qunit and MockJax, I seek to have two tests, simplified here for ease of understanding. One of the following two tests fails, presumably because the two tests run in parallel and thus they do not each get their own detour of `$.ajax()`. (The only difference is the responseText in each.)  Any ideas on a good way to tweak it so that both the following tests pass?

```
function testAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        data: {'a':'b'}
    });
}

asyncTest("testAjax 1", function () {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: { 'name1': 'foo' }
    });

    testAjax().then(
        function (response) {
            deepEqual(response.name1, 'foo', "no name1");
            start();
        },
        function (error) {
            ok(false, "got AJAX error");
            start(); 
        }
    );
});


asyncTest("testAjax 2", function () {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: { 'name1': 'bar' }
    });

    testAjax().then(
        function (response) {
            deepEqual(response.name1, "bar", "no name1");
            start();
        },
        function (error) {
            ok(false, "got AJAX error");
            start();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `$.mockjaxClear()` at the end of each test (e.g. in the `teardown()` method of your module). This destroys the mock and prepares the environment for the next test.

```
function testAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        data: {'a':'b'}
    });
}

module("AJAX tests", {
    teardown: function() {
        $.mockjaxClear();
    }
});
asyncTest("testAjax 1", function () {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: { 'name1': 'foo' }
    });

    testAjax().then(
        function (response) {
            deepEqual(response.name1, 'foo', "no name1");
            start();
        },
        function (error) {
            ok(false, "got AJAX error");
            start();
        }
    );
});


asyncTest("testAjax 2", function () {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/fakeservice/1',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: { 'name1': 'bar' }
    });

    testAjax().then(
        function (response) {
            deepEqual(response.name1, "bar", "no name1");
            start();
        },
        function (error) {
            ok(false, "got AJAX error");
            start();
        }
    );

});
```

See [your adapted example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/L4Kny/).

Comment: In your example, couldn't $.mockjaxClear() execute before the callbacks, and thus ruin the mock?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Yes you are absolutely right. I updated my code and put the call to `$.mockjaxClear()` in the `teardown` of the module. This is actually executed after the test. In the updated jsFiddle I simulated the case you described (using `setTimeout()` to defer the call).